# How to use bootstrap modal with angular 2+ without using jquery?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have included Bootstrap CSS in my project but not the its Javascript or jquery bits. I have figured out how to open and close dropdown menus etc with just angular but haven't been able to trigger the modal.

How do I open (and close) a modal dialog without using Bootstraps's javascript or jQuery?

I am quite new to angular so this might be too obvious for SO. Still creating a question so I can answer it later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without using any Angular plugins this is the easiest way to do it --

Add `(click)="showModal=true"` to the button element which should open the modal.

Add `[ngClass]="{'show': showModal}"` to the modal element.

Since it is not polite to show a modal without a way to close it. Create a close button in the modal and add this `(click)="showModal=false"`.

Add following css to the modal component

```css
.modal.show {
    display:block;
  }
```

So when the button is pressed a 'show' class is added to the modal which unhides the modal. When the close button removes this class the modal is hidden again.

This works for bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two Angular implementations of the Bootstrap components: [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home) and [ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/). Both of them allow to use Bootstrap without jQuery.

Comment: Aware of those. But avoiding so I can learn a bit more angular before taking the easy way.

Comment: A library (ng-*) for a library (bootstrap), for a library (angular), all to avoid a library (jquery) Sounds good! (or just use moment.js, who says there's no room for comedy on SO)

Comment: @DanChase - The goal is to use a library (ng-bootstrap or ngx-bootstrap) that blends naturally with Angular, instead of jQuery which does not. As for the Bootstrap "library", it is just a set of CSS files.

Comment: @ConnorsFan it also has a .js that depends on JQuery and PopperJS, rest assure I do see the point, it's the reason someone made them. My amusement is more along the line of, but Google could have just made Angular with well with JQuery - but it really does, for now.